# Dataset for neural network too large so it crashes my OS. How do I make it more efficient?

Tags: python, optimization, dataset, neural-network

I'm making a simple neural network that will play poker by predicting whether to raise or fold when given a 2 card input. I am training it with a data-set that is 10461x6.

Here's what the first few lines look like:

```
┏━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃  Card1/12 ┇  Card2/12 ┇Suited?┇  Average  ┇Max Difference┇Min Difference┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃0.642857143┇0.285714286┇   0   ┇0.464285714┇ 0.178571429  ┇ 0.178571429  ┃
┣┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┫
┃0.357142857┇0.214285714┇   0   ┇0.285714286┇ 0.071428571  ┇ 0.071428571  ┃
┣┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┫
┃0.857142857┇0.285714286┇   0   ┇0.571428571┇ 0.285714286  ┇ 0.285714286  ┃
┣┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅╋┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┫
┃0.928571429┇0.571428571┇   0   ┇   0.75    ┇ 0.178571429  ┇ 0.178571429  ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

I have this data-set stored in a csv and am converting it to an array in python using `np.genfromtxt()`. This data is then run through the neural network to train it. However I am running into a small problem in that the data-set is so large that it completely crashes my OS.

Here's what I think is happening:

- I don't think its a problem with the array's not being able to hold a 10461x6 array.
- I'm fairly sure it is just that the training is taking so long and using all of the system resources so that appears that it has hung.

I need a more efficient way of training my neural network with this large data set.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
class nn:   
    #make sigma
    def sigma(self,x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    #sigma gradient
    def sigmaDeriv(self,x):
        return x*(1-x)

    def train(self):
        #define datasets
        x = np.genfromtxt('hands.csv', delimiter=',')
        y = np.genfromtxt('correctpred.csv', delimiter=',')[np.newaxis]
        y = y.T

        #seed
        np.random.seed(1)

        w0 = 2*np.random.random((6,10461))-1
        w1 = 2*np.random.random((10461,10461))-1
        w2 = 2*np.random.random((10461,10461))-1
        w3 = 2*np.random.random((10461,1))-1

        #train
        for t in xrange(1000):
            #forward propagation
            l0 = x
            l1 = self.sigma(np.dot(l0, w0))
            l2 = self.sigma(np.dot(l1, w1))
            l3 = self.sigma(np.dot(l2, w2))
            l4 = self.sigma(np.dot(l3, w3))

            #error + change calc
            l4_error = y - l4    
            l4_change = l4_error*self.sigmaDeriv(l4)
            l3_error = l4_change.dot(w3.T)
            l3_change = l3_error * self.sigmaDeriv(l3)
            l2_error = l3_change.dot(w2.T)
            l2_change = l2_error * self.sigmaDeriv(l2)
            l1_error= l2_change.dot(w1.T)
            l1_change = l1_error * self.sigmaDeriv(l1)

            #update weights
            w3 += np.dot(l3.T, l4_change)
            w2 += np.dot(l2.T, l3_change)
            w1 += np.dot(l1.T, l2_change)
            w0 += np.dot(l0.T, l1_change)

        print "Output after training"
        print l4

    nn().train()
```

Comment: FYI [least amount of bits needed for single neuron](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/232032/12359)

Answer (score 0):

Use [stochastic gradient descent](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/OptimizationStochasticGradientDescent/), it was created exactly for this kind of purposes.

Basically instead of using all the data to forward-backward propagate and compute the error (loss), you use only a batch of *b* samples to compute the loss and get the gradients. Then you train for 10461 / b iterations, each time using a different batch of samples, until you see the whole dataset. Once you train in the whole dataset, that is called an epoch. Repeat for 10 epochs or so (tunable by you).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwwWVAgJBcM I found this tutorial, is this along the right lines?

Comment: @Snowsnooks No, that seems to be standard Gradient Descent, not Stochastic Gradient Descent.

Comment: Valenegro Do you have any examples or tutorials for Stochastic GD?